# Improve RSelenium loop, reduce time navigating to the page

Tags: r, performance, selenium, for-loop

I sometimes have to check that our webpages are loading correctly. This usually involves thousands of links. I wrote a for-loop to do this and would like to know if there is a way to cut down the time. I tried doing parallel processing and couldn't figure it out. I'm new to R and selenium is kind of a mystery to me. It seems that waiting for the $navigate() part is where it hangs. It takes about 3-5 sec for this to be complete before moving to the next one.

I tried having 10 browsers going at once and offset so that some steps could run while the page loads but it didn't seem to work. The last assignment I did took 11 hours for 8,200 links. If I could get this to go faster, I'd like to know how. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  library(RSelenium)
  #Reproducible data
    URL <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE,sep=",",text=
            "Link,file,Corr
             http://stackoverflow.com/questions,questions.png,0
             http://www.google.com/,MATCH.png,0
             http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered,unanswered.png,0
             http://www.google.com,google.png,0")

  #Starts Selenium server
    checkForServer()
    startServer()

  #create browsers  
    for(i in 1:4)
      {
       name<- paste("remDr", i, sep="")
       assign(name, remoteDriver$new())
       get(name)$open()
       get(name)$maxWindowSize()
      }

  #Go to site, & save screenshots
  system.time(
    for(i in seq(0,4, by=4))
    { 
      #goes to link, takes 2.5 each
      remDr1$navigate(URL$Link[i+1]) 
      remDr2$navigate(URL$Link[i+2])
      remDr3$navigate(URL$Link[i+3])
      remDr4$navigate(URL$Link[i+4])

      #waits until page loads or max 30 sec, usually takes no time
      remDr1$setTimeout(type = "page load", milliseconds = 30000) 
      remDr2$setTimeout(type = "page load", milliseconds = 30000)
      remDr3$setTimeout(type = "page load", milliseconds = 30000)
      remDr4$setTimeout(type = "page load", milliseconds = 30000)

      #saves screenshot    
      remDr1$screenshot(file = URL$file[i+1])
      remDr2$screenshot(file = URL$file[i+2])
      remDr3$screenshot(file = URL$file[i+3])
      remDr4$screenshot(file = URL$file[i+4])
    }
  )
```

PS: Perhaps this interests someone: I then compare the screenshots to find the ones that match what I'm looking for

```
  library(raster)
  library(doSNOW)
  library(doParallel)
  #Create cluster for parallel processing
    cl <- makeCluster(4)
    registerDoSNOW(cl) 

  #Make a raster of the page I want to find copies of
    MATCH <- raster("MATCH.png")

  #for loop to compare pics
  system.time(
    URL$Corr <- unlist(
      foreach(h=1:4, .packages = "raster", .verbose = T) %dopar%  
      {
        comp <- raster(URL$file[h])
        comp.samp <- round(resample(comp, MATCH, "bilinear"))
        round(cor(getValues(MATCH),getValues(comp.samp), use="complete.obs"), 6)
      })
  )

  MATCH <- URL$file[which(URL$Corr==1)]
  MATCH   #lists pages that match
  stopCluster(cl)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes in java there a library called selnium grid. You can use selenium grid which can help you distribute the load into multiple browsers in multiple machines. You will need more than 1 machine ( Called nodes  where you can run the tests on browsers (upto 5 chrome browser on each node) and fire the tests to a central hub which will control and manage these nodes. [This](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) is a good start. You can also find many questions in  [selenium-grid](/questions/tagged/selenium-grid) which can help you.